# D3 - Maintaining Sort on Data Change

Tags: d3.js

I'm ripping my hair out trying to figure this out.

I have a table being refreshed via WebSocket. It feeds an object with frequency counts. The key is a term. The value is a count. I take this and convert it to an array of arrays, where the top level array contains arrays of the format [key, value]. This works.

I sort and slice the array to get the Top 10. This works.

I feed this 2-dimensional array into d3.

```
d3.select('#table').select('tbody').selectAll('tr').data(dataArray, (element) => {
  return element[0];
});
```

Now, first of all, I can't print this to peek at the update selection. Not on Chrome. Not on Firefox. No access to the selection data, just the `_groups` which does not include the `exit()` elements in the same place so there's no way to verify. But, fine. Whatevs.

I do this:

```
const enterRows = selection.enter().append('tr')
enterRows.append('td').classed('key', true).text((element) => { return element[0]; });
enterRows.append('td').classed('value', true);

enterRows.merge(selection).select('.value').text((element) => { return element[1]; })

selection.exit().remove();
```

At this point, the rows aren't ordered. I would expect them to be ordered. But they're not. Fine. Whatever.

```
selection.order();
```

Does nothing.

What do I do?

EDIT:

Here's a sample of the array as it goes into `data()`:

```
[['B': 5], ['C': 3], ['A': 2]]
```

I can make no sense of the resulting table row order.

I just want to preserve the incoming array order.

Comment: I'm not getting your problem: why should it be ordered? The data binding happens according to the data array order. Can you post a bit of your data array, with the expected outcome as well?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. The table rows are not being ordered in the order of the data array. It's not being preserved.

Comment: Now I see. If you mean the second time on, that is,  the update selections (not the enter one), removing the key function in `data` may help: leave it only `data(dataArray)`.

Comment: I want to match for both the update and enter selections. I found a solution though. Not sure if it's the right one.

Answer (score 0):

`enterRows.merge(selection).order()` does the trick. No idea why it's necessary since ordering is supposed to be stable, but it does.